# integrating cryptopp with simuLTE on omnetpp 4.6

Tags: omnet++

I am a graduate student. I am working with omnet++ 4.6 for some security research. I need to use cryptopp (c++ for all cryptographic algorithms) for this purpose. But, it does not work with that version. Since I cannot switch the versions due to some complications with other projects that need to be integrated, I need something or some way that can help me integrate cryptopp with simuLTE and PTP.

Any suggestions are welcome and appreciated. Thank you!!!

Alekhya Velagapudi

Comment: Could you explain to us what do you mean "it does not work" - it doesn't compile or there is a run-time error?

Comment: It does not compile....

Comment: Could you provide more details about your code and your problem according to [MCV rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?